# Win32 API Combo-box issue

Tags: winapi, combobox

I have a combo-box within my window; and I'm capable of adding elements to the combo-box flawlessly however when I attempt to remove one or all of the items, no items are removed. According to Spy++ the message WM_DELETEITEM sends however the combo-box is not receiving the message.

Comment: Please show some code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't send `WM_DELETEITEM` to delete the item, it gets sent back to you once the control has finished deleting the item. Use [`CB_DELETESTRING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775830%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: Hello Mark, sorry for not being clear in the post. I use SendMessage(hWnd, CB_DELETESTRING, 3, 0); and the message is sent to the parent Window and received as WM_DELETEITEM however no strings within the combo-box are removed. Just to confirm there are 5 strings in the combo-box. Spy++ informs me that the message is sent aka CB_DELETESTRING however the combo-box is not receiving the message to remove a string

Comment: Why are you sending it to the *parent window*? You need to send it to the ComboBox window.

Comment: WM_DELETEITEM is only sent when the ComboBox is owner-drawn. Does the ComboBox have the `CBS_HASSTRINGS` style as well?